# Languages where 3 > 2 > 1 is true

Tags: language-agnostic, comparison

I have written a decimal floating point unit for LaTeX3 (pure macros... that was tough).  In particular, I have to decide how `x < y < z` should be parsed.  I see three options:

- Treat `<` as a left-associative binary operator, so `x < y < z` would be equivalent to `(x < y) < z`.  This is what `C` does: `-1 < 0 < 1` becomes `(-1 < 0) < 1`, thus `1 < 1`, which is `0`.
- Treat `<` as a right-associative binary operator, so `x<y<z` would be equivalent to `x < (y < z)`.  I see no advantage to that option.
- When encountering `<`, read ahead for more comparison operators, and treat `x < y < z` as equivalent to `(x < y) && (y < z)`, where `y` would be evaluated only once.  This is what most non-programmers would expect.  And quite a few LaTeX users are non-programmers.

At the moment I am using the first option, but it does not seem very natural.  I think that I can implement the second case whithout too much overhead.  Should I?

Since that question is subjective, let me ask an objective question: what mainstream languages pick option 3?  I'm interested in the details of what happens with mixed things like `a < b > c == d < e != f`.  I'm also interested in other choices if they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** it only makes sense to parse comparison sequences if they are "pointing into the same direction", and when you don't use `!=`.

**Long answer:** In Python, `3 > 2 > 1` evaluates to `True`. However, I have to say that the implementation used is overly simplistic, because it allows for expressions like `a < b > c == d < e != f`, which are nonsensical in my opinion. The expression [would be interpreted as](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in) `(a < b) and (b > c) and (c == d) and (d < e) and (e != f)`. It's an easy rule, but because it allows for surprising results, I don't like that interpretation.

I propose a more predictable option:

- Consider a proposition `xAyBzCw`. If this proposition is "sensical", it is equivalent to `xAy and yBz and zCw`. For "sensicality", it is necessary that...

  - the values (`x`, `y`, `z`, `w`) are part of the same set `X` (or their types can be unified as such), and
  - the relations (`A`, `B`, `C`) are [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) [binary relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) on `X`, and
  - for every ordered pair of relations `A` and `B`, there exists a relation `C`, such that `xAy and yBz` implies `xCz` for all `x`, `y`, `z`; this relation is also subject to these restrictions.

Regarding the last rule, you want to be able to say that `1 < 2 = a < 4` is equivalent to `1<2 and 2=a and a<4`, but also that `1<2 and 1<a and 1<4`. To say the latter, you must know how `=` and `<` interact.

You can't use `!=` in my option, because it isn't transitive. But you also can't say `1 < 3 > 2`, `2 < 3 > 1`, or `1 < 3 > 1`, unless you have a relation `?` such that `1?2`, `2?1` and `1?1` (basically, it would be a relation allows any pair).

From a syntactical standpoint: you want to treat relational operators as special operators (`+` is more of a functional operator), kind of like in your third option.

Comment: Interesting.  In my case, I only have one type available ---floating points (integers are automatically converted to floats when the target is a float)--- so there will be no issue with types.  I presume that your approach would be to produce a `NaN` as the result for `1 < 3 > 2`, probably after raising the `invalid operation` flag (cf IEEE 754 2008)?

Comment: Probably, if you don't want to implement this type checking statically and if you also don't want to have boolean logic values (`True`, `False`, and a boolean counterpart of `NaN`; again, only if you don't want to implement a proper type system).

Comment: LaTeX is an interpreted macro language.  In particular, since it's not compiled, there is no way AFAIK to do static checking of those comparison relations.  I think that Python would also have to raise an exception in case it decided to forbid `1 < 3 > 2`.

Comment: Because Python has a very limited set of suitable relational operators, that might even be caught by the grammar. When implemented, it would result in a syntax error. TeX (and thus LaTeX) is Turing-complete, so you can implement a type checker. I would advise against it, though ;)

Comment: You're right about Python.  About TeX, Turing completeness does not mean "can do anything" but rather "can compute anything": you could implement a type-checker for your favorite typed language in TeX.  However, there is really only one type in TeX: macros (think strings).  Static type checking is then checking that the content of those strings is compatible with a given structure (float, int), which looks a lot more uncomputable to me (statically) than type checking normally is.  Run-time type checking is doable, but I need to produce some kind of result: invalid operation is as good as any.

Comment: After trying to write a precise spec, I realized that checking for the consistency of comparison operators is somewhat non-local: in `a < b == c == d == ... == y > z`, we can only detect the error after reading all the other comparisons.  The implementation can get messy really quickly.  Also, in the context of IEEE floating points, there are four relations: `<`, `=`, `>`, and `?`, and any combination of those (and a leading `!`).  Deciding which chains of comparisons should be allowed is messy.  I will simply implement Python's blissful lack of worry.

Comment: It is indeed not local. In my option, you would have to *track* whether a chain is increasing (has only `<`, `<=`, `==`) or decreasing (has only `>`, `>=`, `==`). You only need three distinguishing values (increasing, decreasing, or "so far only `==`"), but you still have to inspect the whole chain.

Comment: Your approach works for `<`, `>`, `=`, and combinations.  However, I think that the "not-comparable" relation that IEEE 754 mandates (`x?y` is true if and only if either `x` or `y` is `NaN`) complicates things.  For instance `!?` ("comparable") is transitive `(a !? b) and (b !? c)` implies `a !? c`, so following your definition would allow `a !? b !? c`, and in fact also `a < b > c`, since that implies `a !? c`.  Another case which may or may not be allowed is `a < b <? c`, which always implies `a <? c`. --- Basically, I'd say your idea is good, but maybe unrealistic.

Answer (score 2):

Python chains relational operators. Which gets interesting when you hit `in` and `is`, since they're considered relational as well.

```
>>> 1 < 2 in [True, False]
False
>>> 1 < 2 in [2, 4]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

[J](http://www.jsoftware.com) evaluates statements right-to-left so that:

```
3 > 2 > 1
```

Becomes first

```
2 > 1
```

Which resolves to true, represented as 1, thus:

```
3 > 1
```

Which also resolves to true, thus 1. The opposite operator `<` would result in false, whereas the whole statement happens to be true. So you're no further with J.

Your main issue is that your initial representation:

```
3 > 2 > 1
```

is human shorthand for

```
(3 > 2) AND (2 > 1)
```

So while reading ahead seems icky, it's really what the representation needs. Unless of course there's some Python magic, as others have stated.